# Chromium 58 canvas.captureStream

Tags: javascript, canvas, mediastream

I'm streaming MediaRecorder data over websockets, everything works but Chromium 58 fails on the client side, lower versions work as expected. The video tag stays blank, and the following error message gets spammed into console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

media-internals give me:

```
Timestamp Property  Value
00:00:00 00 pipeline_state  kCreated
00:00:00 00 event WEBMEDIAPLAYER_CREATED
00:00:00 00 url blob:http://localhost/2784e88e-e864-49aa-92fb-ec7574ae36a0
00:00:00 00 pipeline_state  kStarting
00:00:02 85 error Unsupported video codec_id V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
00:00:02 85 error Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=131072 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
00:00:02 86 pipeline_error  chunk demuxer: append failed
00:00:02 86 pipeline_state  kStopping
00:00:02 86 pipeline_state  kStopped
```

The client sided sourceBuffer uses the following settings:

```
sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(`video/webm; codecs="vp8"`);
sourceBuffer.mode = "sequence";
// and chunks is an array of uint8arrays
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunks[ii]);
```

I need to use Chromium 58 because the bug is fixed, where the canvas we call captureStream on doesn't have to be attached to the body anymore.

Comment: Sounds a little bit too broad to get an answer. Does it throw this error since the beginning ? What is the status of your canvas' stream ? Did you draw anything on the canvas before capturing the stream ? Does this also happen when you do attach the canvas in the document ? You are talking about MediaRecorder, is it able to record this stream correctly ? Could you try to make an [mcve] (without the server side of course).